# Adding dynamic fields to nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have node `A` with fields like `name: string` etc. I also want the user to be able to add some dynamic fields `(name, type, value)`, and I want the user to add multiple fields only to his account. In SQL, I would solve this with multiple tables and relations (probably).

How can I handle it with `graphdb`?

I was thinking about an array of objects in a node, but I don't know if that's gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameterized Cypher queries and run either of the `SET` syntax variant:

```
MATCH (myNode ...)
SET myNode = $props
```

or

```
MATCH (myNode ...)
SET myNode += $props
```

This also works with relationships.

The first `SET` variant overwrites all properties of the target.

The second one adds new properties and overwrites only the existing property whose name clash with the names in the $props dictionary.